# Equally spaced points on x-axis in exponential distribution probplot/qqplot

Tags: python, exponential-distribution, qq-plot

I have a sample distribution and want to check if it is exponential. For that I am trying a `qqplot` and `probplot`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import scipy
from scipy import stats
```

```py
d1 = np.random.exponential(scale=3, size=100)
scipy.stats.probplot(d1, dist="expon", plot=plt)
```

produces

[image]

And

```py
sm.qqplot(d1, dist=scipy.stats.expon)
```

produces

[image]

#### **Problem**

My problem is that in both cases, the points are not equally distributed, i.e. evenly spaced on the x-axis, e.g. there are much more points in the left half of the x-axis than of the right half.

I tried various axis modifications, such as `plt.yscale("log")`, `plt.xscale("log")` and none produce the desired result.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What else could I try? I feel like since my points are not equally distributed (i.e. evenly spaced on the x-axis), the few outliers on the right distort the picture (or dont they?), even though most of the points on the left look fine. If they were evenly spaced those outliers would not matter that much. Maybe I am also misunderstanding these plots.

#### **Small Update**

Claryfying why I am asking this question. I have this data (which I can not share unfortunately. The probplot looked like this:

```py
scipy.stats.probplot(vol_cb["volume"], dist="expon", plot=plt)
```

[image]

Which I thought was ok. But then I looked closer into it by setting x and y lim:

```py
scipy.stats.probplot(vol_cb["volume"], dist="expon", plot=plt)
plt.ylim(-10,200)
plt.xlim(-.1,1.8)
```

and it then looked like this

[image]

THe fit is much worse in my opinion, and I felt the first picture did not really highlight this because all the left side points were very crammed together.

Comment: I am at a loss to know what you're asking here. It's not I think about coding, and code used incidentally to illustrate a statistical question is fine here. You have some real data and are comparing them with an exponential distribution: the quantile plot (your software insists on calling it a probability plot)  is telling you that the fit is fairly good for lower values and poor for higher values. However, there seems to be some fine structure too (e.g. repeated values that hint at some rounding).  Where you go from here depends on your goals for analysing these data.

Comment: Its probably just some confusion from my side since I am new to probability plots and/or qqplots. I think in the meantime I have understood that since the x-axis are the quantiles that it would not be feasible to have points distributed across all quantiles evenly since that is not how quantiles work. Instead, no matter what you do, points are most concrentated in some quantiles and more sparse in others. So i that sense I would agree that my question is potentially weird and cant be really answered...

Comment: Quantiles are equally spaced in a uniform distribution and not otherwise (unless you select quantiles that are uniformly spaced on a selected scale).

Comment: yes I think I understand the fallacy of my question now. Thanks for helping

Comment: @NickCox It's possible that I misunderstood the intent of your second comment above, but if  $Y\sim \text{exponential}(\mu)$ (say, in scale parameterization), then I don't think that $V=\log(Y)$ has a uniform distribution. Consider that taking logs of a variable on $(0,\infty)$ would give a variable on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Rather, $U=F_Y(Y) = 1-\exp(-Y/\mu)$ would be standard uniform, as would $1-U=\exp(-Y/\mu)$. This doesn't alter the underlying point being made in the comment, of course, but I figured it was worth mentioning that the transformation was different.

Comment: I believe applying this would correspond to a P-P plot.

Comment: @Glen_b My intent was benign, but my content was wrong, so many thanks for pointing that out. I had a garbled memory of  procedures following from your equations, which I  implemented a while back for Stata https://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s357702.htm https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s357701.html